# How to solve this problem using Javascript

Tags: javascript

In weather.dat there are data with meteorological surveys. The first column contains the day of the month, while the second and the third contain respectively the temperature maximum and minimum for that day.
Write a program that, given the input file, returns the day with the smallest temperature range.

this is the link of a the data displayed in Atom:
[image]

The file that contains these data has a .dat extension, I have never used it so far so I don't even know how should I retrieve these data in my script! (should I rewrite them directly in the arrays?)

Please help!

Comment: The `split()` method can be used to convert the file into arrays.

Comment: First step, load the file with fetch. Second step break it out to lines with a split, Third step, loop over the lines and split on tabs (Or what ever the delimiter is)

Comment: plenty of examples out on the net to read CSV files. It is basically the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In general files are separated into txt and binary files so extracting data is general for these two file types. File extensions are often used just for clarification.

[How to extract data from a txt(.dat) file](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=extract%20data%20from%20a%20.dat%20file%20javascript)
[Javascript file reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

As well idea for the given task:

- Save days into a collection (optional)
- Iterate over the collection of days
- Calculate the temperature range for each day (Max - Min)
- Find the min value